# Cocos2d-x CCRef.h Error

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x-3.0

I'm new in Cocos2d-x development and I have the problem that everytine I want to compile my game for an other device than my iPhone 5s, it gives me an error that every type name of a class in my `CCRef.h` is a fault.

I tried to compile it for every iOS version as possible and with many Cocos 2d-x versions. At the moment I'm using Cocos 2d-x version 3.6, the currently Xcode version and an iPhone with iOS 8.3!

I hope you can help me fix this!

Comment: Please elaborate your question.

Comment: Please remove the image and add the errors as text; that image cannot be read.